# Carousel transition issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a carousel with 3 images. When i click next , the next image loads after 1 second. but during this 1 second I can still the previous image. I tried adding a loading gif so that when the next is clicked the gif shows up and then the image loads, but it doesnt show up between carousel transitions on IE and Firefox and works fine on chrome.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Use jsfiddle to support your question. But your problem seems generic with IE CSS support / Firefox. Mention IE version assuming "edge" ..??

Comment: Add your code to your answer please